# How to use AWS SNS push notification for many apps

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS for an app A to push notifications, and I want an app B to also use AWS SNS push notifications on the same AWS account. So how can I separate the topics belonging to this app and the topics belonging to other apps?
Currently, I am using a user for a topic so I want to separate the users of app A and app B on topic management on AWS SNS console.

Comment: Just create a separate Amazon SNS topic for each app. What specific problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein With app A, I have each topic for each user (ex: user_id: 9 -> topic: user-9). On app B I have each topic for each user too(ex: user_id: 9 -> topic: user-9). Its purpose is to send notifications to certain users. I want to separate topics for app A and app B. How can I differentiate between two apps when they share the same topic or is there a better way to differentiate the two apps? Sorry, my bad English.

Comment: Such usage of Amazon SNS is not standard. SNS is designed to send notifications to multiple subscribed users per topic. It is _not_ meant to be used with "one recipient per topic". If you are sending messages to apps, then you can use the `Publish()` command with a `TargetArn`, without requiring a Topic.